# PowerBI Rate Of Change

Tags: sql-server, statistics, powerbi, dax, window-functions

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Date, Value
01/01/2020 13:00, 2
01/01/2020 14:00, 3
01/01/2020 15:00, 4
01/01/2020 16:00, 9
01/01/2020 17:00, 2
```

I want to be able to have a measure created in PowerBI that looks at the Percent of Change from one to the other. Ideally, it would be great if I could get the Max, Average, and Min Rate of Change. Looking around, it seems like you would have to "loop" over the data to do this, and Looping in DAX is not really a thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. We are querying the data live, so the idea of creating separate "temp" tables really isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only have one `Value` for each `Date` and that there are no duplicate `Date` values, you can get the rate of change between just one `Date` value in your filter context (the most recent in the example below) and the `Date` value before it doing something like this:

```
RateOfChange = 
var cd = calculate(max(YourTable[Date]))
var cv = calculate(max(YourTable[Value]),YourTable[Date] = cd)
var pd = calculate(max(YourTable[Date]),YourTable[Date] < cd)
var pv = calculate(max(YourTable[Value]),YourTable[Date] = pd)
return
divide(cv - pv, pv, 0)
```

[image: 1]

Though as you can see, it isn't exactly the most elegant or efficient at scale nor will it provide you the min, average and max change across the dataset.  Ideally you would be importing this data and generating a calculated column to hold the `Rate of Change` value within each row.  That way you *would* be able to get a min, average and max.

If you absolutely have to resort to direct query, you should look into whether you can either add some tables to report out of or at the least some views that help you get the data into the format you require for the reporting.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want window functions. You do not describe how the "change rate" should be calculated, but a typical interpretation is:

```
    select
    avg(change_rate) avg_change_rate,
    max(change_rate) max_change_rate,
    min(change_rate) min_change_rate
from (
    select 
        1.0 * (lead(value) over(order by date) - value) / value change_rate
    from mytable
) t
```

Comment: How would you embed this in a PowerBI Measure?